# Broadcast mDNS for another device

Tags: networking, bonjour, mdns, avahi

I have a custom/experimental device (D) on my home LAN with a static IP running an HTTP server. For reasons that are not important to this question, (D) cannot run mDNS. I have another full-fledged Ubuntu Server (S) on the same LAN*. I would like the server S to broadcast and respond to mDNS on behalf of D.
Can this be done?

I can see that avahi [can be configured](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=218630) to advertise arbitrary services but it is not clear if/how this can be done when the services are on another machine altogether.

*(connected to the same Ethernet switch for the moment)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, any host can respond to any mDNS name with any DNS records it wants.

1. If you only want to make the plain hostname (`foo.local`) resolvable through mDNS, define it in the `/etc/avahi/hosts` file. See [avahi.hosts(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/avahi-daemon/avahi.hosts.5.en.html).

   ```
   192.168.1.37       toaster.local
   2001:db8:108:2::37 toaster.local
   ```

   The system will now respond to mDNS queries for all names listed in this file, and will provide the corresponding IP addresses.
2. If you additionally want to publish DNS-SD services on behalf of another system, you can do so using Avahi `*.service` files. See [avahi.service(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/avahi-daemon/avahi.service.5.en.html) for more details.

   You can specify any hostname you want in the `<host-name>` tag when defining the service, as long as it's already resolvable by itself (that is, you must do step #1 first in order for this to work).

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <service-group>
       <name>Toaster</name>
       <service>
           <type>_sftp-ssh._tcp</type>
           <host-name>toaster.local</host-name>
           <port>22</port>
       </service>
   </service-group>
   ```